# System.UnauthorizedAccessException trying to open file from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an error in code when try to open a jpg file.

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string path, string title, string width, string height)
    {

        string imageFormat = path.Split('\\')[path.Split('\\').Length - 1].Split('.')[1];
        byte[] imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    ....
```

I have this exception

```
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso '\\server2008\Volumenes\intranet\Intranet 01\1645\2\6115753.jpg'.
```

I can access to this file and open it in windows explorer, and apply  IIS_IUSRS to this folder. Im trying to configure IIS but i dont know what i need configure. This Site its in DefaultAppPool and try puting LocalServices and LocalSystem in identity but this don't work.

I read that i dont need put any code in web.config, is only a configuration in IIS.

Thanks for help

Update:

I have the same error in ascx files

```
<%=Html.Action("GetUserImage", "Telefonos", new { path = imagen, clase="usrimg" })%>
```

In this case I have this exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
```

{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Deny access to '\server2008\Volumenes\intranet\UserPictures\image.jpg'

Comment: I wont post this as an answer, since it's more of a suggestion and there's a decent chance it's not the issue... But I worked on a project recently where this exception was thrown because I was trying to create a subdirectory to hold a file from a server, and I had read permissions but not write permissions to actually create it.

Comment: You can open from Windows Explorer but it's runs with a different user. Moreover security permissions, by default, forbid to go out your root folder

Comment: DangerZone: I only need open this file and put it in an image tag <img>,  Adriano Repetti: Yes i can open this file, i have permission to put, read and delete in this server folder

Comment: I mean: do you have that permissions for **IIS user**? Interactive use you use with Windows Explorer and IIS user are different (with different permission sets).

Comment: Maybe its the problem, where I have to change this? In app Pool configuration? Im using DefaultAppPool